# Strange behaviour with alert in mathmode

Tags: beamer, math-mode, color

I got this unexpected behaviour when I change colour to `alerted text` in `mathmode`. In particular, `alerted text.fg` seems to change only when `\alert` is called again. Changing with `\colorlet` affect only the colour inside `mathmode`.

Here an example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}{Title}
    $\begingroup\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}\alert{blue}\endgroup+\textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}$  These should be \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}, \alert{red} and \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}
    
    $\begingroup\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}\alert{blue}\endgroup\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}+\textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}$  These should be \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}, \alert{red} and \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}
    
    $\begingroup\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}\alert{blue}\endgroup\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}\colorlet{alerted text.fg}{red}+\textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}$  These should be \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}, \alert{red} and \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}
    
    $\begingroup\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=blue}\alert{blue}\endgroup\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}\alert{}+\textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}$  These should be \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}, \alert{red} and \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really need to change back and forth the colors? Wouldn't it be simpler to apply just the color you want without `\alert`?

Answer (score 1):

`\setbeamercolor{}{}` itself does not yet create the `.fg` and `.bg` colours, they are only created when the beamer colour is used.

But instead of changing the alert colour back and forth, you could create more alert-like macros with whatever colour you like -- or simply use `\structure`, that's blue by default.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{foo}{fg=green}

\newenvironment<>{fooenv}{\begin{altenv}#1%
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{foo}\usebeamerfont{foo}\usebeamertemplate{foo text begin}}
    {\usebeamertemplate{foo text end}}{\color{.}}{}\ignorespaces}{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\end{altenv}}

\newcommand<>{\foo}[1]{\begin{fooenv}#2\relax#1\end{fooenv}}


\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}{Title}
    $\structure{blue}+\textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}$  These should be \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}, \alert{red} and \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}
    
    $\foo{green}+\textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}$  These should be \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}, \alert{red} and \textcolor{alerted text.fg}{red}    

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]